# VBA : Sort limit after 8 rows

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, limit

I am using the sort function in VBA regularly and I tried a new way to sort a table with 20 rows based on three different keys. I used the three keys combined :

```
Range("H3:Q22").Sort 
Key1:=Range("I2"), Order1:=xlDescending, 
Key2:=Range("P2"), Order2:=xlDescending, 
Key3:=Range("N2"), Order3:=xlDescending
```

And also tried a unique function :

```
Sub SortMultipleColumns()
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
         .SortFields.Add key:=Range("I2"), Order:=xlDescending
         .SortFields.Add key:=Range("P2"), Order:=xlDescending
         .SortFields.Add key:=Range("N2"), Order:=xlDescending
         .SetRange Range("H2:Q22")
         .Header = xlYes
         .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

In both situations, I get the following result :

[image]

It looks like I get the right sorting on the first 8 rows and then nothing, it's not sorted based on any key. Do you know if there is a restriction to the number of rows of data cells that can be sorted this way?

Until now, I only used it to sort 4 rows and it was working perfectly. I'd be surprised Microsoft implemented a function that can only work on such little data.

Comment: It works for me. I tried `Range.Sort` and `Worksheet.Sort` and saw no issues with any of the 3 keys. I was not able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Are you sure all those numbers are actually integers?

Comment: I understood, there were actually data grouping on the first ten rows so it actually counted as two different tables. Even using the sorting from Excel I got the same result, that's when it hit me.
Anyway, thanks for your support, hoping it will help if you ever get in the same situation.